# Стильный круглый прогресс бар на чистом CSS

Tags: css, jquery, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Помогите реализовать след. прогресс бар:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя попытка: https://jsfiddle.net/rh29egx0/

Моя попытка #2: https://jsfiddle.net/hmtk57f8/

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" class="pie">
  <circle class="chart" r="25%" cx="50%" cy="50%"></circle>
  <circle class="background" r="25%" cx="50%" cy="50%" stroke-dasharray="80 100"></circle>
</svg>
```

Вроде все хорошо, но визуально не совсем то...

Comment: Хорошо бы вариант регулировки процентного заполнения не через stroke-dasharray, потому что он криво работает, например тут: https://jsfiddle.net/yj5r12f8/

Comment: Тут все есть: http://jsfiddle.net/andsens/mLA7X/

Comment: *на чистом CSS как бы намекает на то что без JS нужно :)

Comment: Там на чистом CSS, маленький код на JS просто выставляет его рандомно, если его стереть, то все будет работать и без него.

Comment: Ок, попробую переписать под себя, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее как-то так:

https://jsfiddle.net/b3h0tqye/57/

```
  <svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" class="pie">
     <circle class="background" r="27.5%" cx="50%" cy="50%" style="stroke-width:1;"></circle>
     <circle class="background" r="22%" cx="50%" cy="50%" style="stroke-width:1;"></circle>
     <circle class="chart" r="25%" cx="50%" cy="50%" stroke-dasharray="80 100"></circle>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Где в stroke-dasharray="80 100" 80 = заполнено на 80% процентов.

Answer (score 6):

### Варианты с анимацией заполнения прогрессбара и вывода процентов

---

***SVG анимация***

---

Использован код ответа автора и добавлена анимация `stroke-dasharray`
Для вывода процентов заполнения прогрессбара используется jQuery

```js
var count = $(('#count'));
$({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: count.text() }, {
  duration: 4000,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function () {
    count.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter)+ "%");
  }
});
```

```css
.pie{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border-radius:50%;
            
        }
        .pie .background{
            fill:none;
            stroke:#ffb734;
            stroke-width:4;
           
        }
         .pie .chart{
            fill:none;
            stroke: #ffb734;
            stroke-width:4;
        }
</style>        
<body>
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" class="pie">
     <circle class="background" r="27.5%" cx="50%" cy="50%" style="stroke-width:1;"></circle>
     <circle class="background" r="22%" cx="50%" cy="50%" style="stroke-width:1;"></circle>
     <circle class="chart" stroke-dashoffset="25" r="25%" cx="50%" cy="50%" stroke-dasharray="0 0">
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray"  begin="0s" dur="4s" values="0 100;100 0" />
     </circle>  
     <text id="count" x="50%" y="55%" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" dy="0" font-size="10">100%</text>
  </svg>
</body>
```

---

***CSS анимация***

---

```js
var count = $(('#count'));
$({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: count.text() }, {
  duration: 4000,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function () {
    count.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter)+ "%");
  }
});
```

```css
 .pie{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border-radius:50%;
            
        }
        .pie .background{
            fill:none;
            stroke:#ffb734;
            stroke-width:4;
           
        }
          .chart{
            fill:none;
            stroke: #ffb734;
            stroke-width:4; 
            stroke-dashoffset:25;
            stroke-dasharray:0, 100;
            animation: progress 4s linear forwards;
        }
        
        @keyframes progress {
        100% {stroke-dasharray: 100,0 }
        }
        
</style>
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" class="pie">
     <circle class="background" r="27.5%" cx="50%" cy="50%" style="stroke-width:1;"></circle>
     <circle class="background" r="22%" cx="50%" cy="50%" style="stroke-width:1;"></circle>
     <circle class="chart"  r="25%" cx="50%" cy="50%" stroke-dasharray="0 0">
         </circle>  
     <text id="count" x="50%" y="55%" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" dy="0" font-size="10">100%</text>
  </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: Круто! Спасибо что делитесь!

Comment: Палец вверх привычнее, тем не менее лайкнул т.е. поставил голосо :)